# How to allow exact match in nginx location and throw 404 for unmatched location

Tags: nginx

I want to match the exact location in nginx, if the location has extra text or parameters it should show a 404 page. for example `http://localhost:8080/yes` shouldn't display the index page but show 404 page. Here's my `.conf` file

```
root /var/www/assets/;
index index.html;

location / {
    default_type text/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location /data {
    default_type text/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /data.html =404;
}

location /voice {
     default_type text/html;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /voice.html =404;
}
```

for example I want to match `/data` only, no `/dataaa` or `/datas` and show 404 page if the location doesn't match the above locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an *exact* match to `/data` then your location need to be specified with a `=` like so

```
location = /data {
    default_type text/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /data.html =404;
}
```

From the [Nginx manual about `location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

> [D]efining “location = /” will speed up the processing of these requests, as **search terminates right after the first comparison**.

(emphasis mine)